# pg-promise Dynamic Columns with CTE

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

I am trying to UPDATE my database with an AJAX request using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) on the express server.

So far everything is working, but now I want to use a CTE (WITH) to update two tables, which is working too. What I want to do now is to be able to have dynamic columns, depending on the PUT request.

For clarification:

1. Request

   ```
   {
       "dob": "01.01.1970",
       "email": "example@example.com",
       "street": "street 1",
   }
   ```
2. Request

   ```
   { 
       "dob": "01.01.1970",
       "email": "example@example.com",
       "phone": "0000",
       "tag": "blue",
   }
   ```

I tried the following and it is working, but my questions are:

1. Am I using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) correctly?
2. Is this approach still SQL injection safe (*:raw*)?
3. Is there a better way to achieve the same results?

**QueryFile.sql**

```
WITH update_table_one AS (
    UPDATE table_one SET username=${username} 
    WHERE identification_number=${identification_number}
    RETURNING identification_number
)       
UPDATE table_two SET ${fromSet:raw}
WHERE identification_number=(SELECT identification_number FROM update_table_one);
```

**Server.js**

```
let qf = // ...QueryFile
let helpers = pgp.helpers;
let user = req.params.user;
let body = req.body;

let dbBody = {
    username: user,
    identification_number: 'ABC123',
    fromSet: helpers.sets(body)
};

db.oneOrNone(qf, dbBody)
    .then(data => {
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Yes!' });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'No!' });
    });
```

**Addition to the initial question (relates to my question in the comments):**

```
    { 
        "dob": "01.01.1970",
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "street": "street 1",
        "phone": "0000",
        "tag": "blue",
        "group": "students",
        "password": "hash",
        "track": "one",
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) correctly?

Almost. Your query doesn't return anything, so use of method [oneOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#oneOrNone) is logically incorrect, it should be [none](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#none) instead.

> Is this approach still SQL injection safe (:raw)?

Yes, because even though you are injecting raw sets, the columns are pre-escaped within the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) automatically, based on their JavaScript type, so any injection attempt is foiled right there.

> Is there a better way to achieve the same results?

Only if you know all the columns in advance, you could pre-declare them as a [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html), for better performance and/or type conversion. But other than that, no.

Also keep in mind, that if you call `helpers.sets(body)` passing in no columns, it will return an empty string, as [per the API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.sets), which in turn will result into an invalid `UPDATE`.

Comment: **Thank you very much!** So if I know all possible columns (I've edited the question), I can use the ColumnSet to achieve the same result and select it dynamicly depending on the Object the user sends? And the pre-defined ColumnSet picks the correct sets? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @abergavenny yes. And you would use `skip` logic on all the optional columns.